# Checar itens cadastrados no checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Estou programando em C# no Visual Studio 2015, e tenho um form com um checkedListBox com nomes de vários cursos (O cadastro é de um aluno).

Ao marcar e salvar, ele salva o cadastro do aluno na tabela alunos,  e me apresenta ao meu datagridview, onde ele server para visualização

Preciso agora que quando eu editar o cadastro do aluno, os checkedListBox apareçam checados, nas opções que foram marcadas na hora da inserção, porém não estou conseguindo fazer isso, eu estou utilizando o próprio datagridview para realizar o update, ou seja quando eu clico na celula do datagridview ele me abre outro form para fazer o update do cadastro, so nao to conseguindo pegar as informação do meu checkedlistbox.

Resumindo:

Preciso puxar do banco  e marcar as opções do CheckedListBox que foram marcados na inserção do aluno.

Esse é meu codigo que joga as informação do meu datagridview para meu form de update.

```
private void DG_edit_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Tela_EditarAluno fmr = new Tela_EditarAluno();

        fmr.TB_cod.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Cod"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_nome.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_idade.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Idade"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_endereco.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Endereço"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_quadra_lote.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Quadra"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.MD_telefoneFixo.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Residencial"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.MD_telefoneCel.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Celular"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_cidade.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Cidade"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_uf.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Uf"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_email.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Email"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_nomepai.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Pai"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.TB_nomemae.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Mãe"].Value.ToString();
        fmr.CB_ativo.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Ativo"].Value.ToString();



        fmr.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Eu me esqueci de mencionar o meu checkedlistbox, por esse motivo eu tirei dois prints da tela inicial de cadastramento e tela de edição. inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

essa imagem é da tela de edição.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

essa é minha tela inicial para cadastramento com o meu checkedlistbox "ATIVIDADES","OBS: essa coluna é da minha tabela alunos" eu possuo uma coluna Atividades onde ele joga as minhas STRINGS que foram inseridas pelo checkedlistbox. e quando clico na celula do datagridview no como no primeiro print de editar ele tem que verificar e marcar os itens que foram cadastrados na tela de cadastramento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você falou que não está conseguindo popular o listbox com os valores selecionados, onde está a rotina de recuperar os valores do BD e popular no form?

Comment: Denis bom dia. eu estou usando o checkedlistbox, nao o listbox, reformulei minha pergunta com os prints, postei o codigo para pegar as informação do datagridview e jogar no outro form, porem nao sei a função para checar os itens que foram cadastrados atraves do checkedlistbox, e marcalos de acordo com o que foi cadastrados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa obter o índice do item do `CheckedListBox` que você precisa editar. Para facilitar, estou assumindo que você quer obter o item do `CheckedListBox` através do seu nome (label).
Utilize este código:

```
private int GetItemIndex(string item)
{
    int index = 0;

    foreach (object o in myCheckedListBox.Items)
    {
        if (item == o.ToString())
        {
            return index;
        }

        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Obtenha o índice do item:

```
var index = GetItemIndex("Nome do Item do checkedBoxList");
```

Então você pega o valor do campo da sua DataGridView que vai definir se o item estará checado ou não.

```
bool checked = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Ativo"].Value.ToString() == "Sim"; // Exemplo
```

Então você define se aquele item do `CheckedListBox` que você obteu o índice estará checado ou não:

```
myCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(index, checked);
```

Faça isso para cada item do seu `CheckedListBox`.

Referências:
[Obter Item do CheckedListBox por Nome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109675/checkedlistbox-search-for-an-item-by-text)

**Edit:**

Você tem seu objeto `checkedListBox` no seu form, nele estão contidos todos os checkboxes.

Você tem gravado no banco de dados, ou no caso, na sua `dataGridView` se aqueles check boxes estão selecionados (tickados) ou não.

Para checar cada item do seu `checkedListBox`, é necessário usar o método `SetItemChecked` do `CheckedListBox`, passando o index do item que você quer checar

Exemplo:

```
// Obter checkBox de Yoga

int indexCbYoga = GetItemIndex("Yoga"); // Utilizando o método GetItemIndex que você vai precisar copiar no seu código, no code behind do seu form

// Pegar o valor da dataGridView que diz se a Yoga está marcada

bool yogaChecked = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Atividades"].Value.ToString().Contains("Yoga"); // Ou contém "Yoga", não sei como você guarda isto na sua `DataGridView`

// Checar o valor do Yoga no seu `checkedListBox`

myCheckedListBox.SetItemChecked(indexCbYoga, yogaChecked); // Se yogaChecked for true, checa o checkBox Yoga, senão, deixa desmarcado.
```

**Edit 2:**

```
private void DG_edit_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Tela_EditarAluno fmr = new Tela_EditarAluno();

    fmr.TB_cod.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Cod"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_nome.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Nome"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_idade.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Idade"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_endereco.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Endereço"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_quadra_lote.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Quadra"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.MD_telefoneFixo.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Residencial"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.MD_telefoneCel.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Celular"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_cidade.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Cidade"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_uf.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Uf"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_email.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Email"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_nomepai.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Pai"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.TB_nomemae.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Mãe"].Value.ToString();
    fmr.CB_ativo.Text = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Ativo"].Value.ToString();

    // Obter checkBox de Yoga

    int indexCbYoga = GetItemIndex(fmr.chekedListBox, "Yoga"); // fmr.chekedListBox é o nome do seu CheckedListBox dentro do seu form. 

    // Pegar o valor da dataGridView que diz se a Yoga está marcada

    bool yogaChecked = DG_edit.CurrentRow.Cells["Atividade"].Value.ToString().Contains("Yoga"); // Ou contém "Yoga", não sei como você guarda isto na sua `DataGridView`

    // Checar o valor do Yoga no seu `checkedListBox`

    fmr.checkedListBox.SetItemChecked(indexCbYoga, yogaChecked); // Se yogaChecked for true, checa o checkBox Yoga, senão, deixa desmarcado.

    // Fazer o mesmo para as outras opções além de Yoga...

    fmr.ShowDialog();

}

private int GetItemIndex(CheckedListBox checkedListBox, string item)
{
    int index = 0;

    foreach (object o in checkedListBox.Items)
    {
        if (item == o.ToString())
        {
            return index;
        }

        index++;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: MurariAlex bom dia. cara ainda fiquei com duvidas, nessa solução que você postou

Comment: Bom dia, @Lucas_Furby, fiz uma edição com um exemplo, espero que ajude

Comment: Entendi @MurariAlex, nesse caso nao preciso informar nome da minha coluna, teria so que referenciar cada string do checkedlistbox ? e outra coisa  eu teria que mexer na meu banco para fazer essa inserção por que no seu codigo esta como "int", o meu banco esta como varchar... eu estou utilizando sql server 2008

Comment: O `int` no caso é o indice do box Yoga dentro do seu `checkedListBox` no form, não tem nada a ver com o banco. Para seu objeto checkedListBox saber que você quer marcar ou desmarcar o checkBox de Yoga, você precisa passar o indice dele.

Comment: Fiz uma pequena edição, ali na váriavel `yogaChecked` coloquei como você pode obter se a Yoga está marcada.

Comment: eu vou tentar aqui @MurariAlex, e te falo se deu certo.

Comment: cara eu nao consegui implantar isso... eu coloquei o seu codigo dentro da função do datagridview, ele me retornar erro alegando que a coluna atividades nao foi encontrada, mais ela esta no meu banco.

Comment: Atenção no nome da coluna, no meu exemplo está "Atividades" mas no seu print está "Atividade", então acredito que você tenha copiado o nome errado, modifique o código e revise os nomes para que eles se adaptem ao seu código.

Comment: cara voce poderia me add no skype so para tirar umas duvidas tecnologia@moveisbonarte.com.br

Comment: Estou no trabalho e não possuo Skype aqui... só posso lhe ajudar por aqui.

Comment: blz, vamos lá... você tinha perguntado se o meu checkedlistbox era selecionado ou tikado.. ele é selecionado, tenho uma função que faz a inserção das strings buscando na collections, e add na coluna atividade... minha duvida é tenho que colocar esse codigo que voce postou dentro do datagridview ? e como vou chamar o outro form para verificar

Comment: essa é minha função do checkedlist string str = "";
                if (CLB_atividade.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < CLB_atividade.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (str == "")
                        {
                            str = CLB_atividade.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            str += "," + CLB_atividade.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                        }
                    }

Comment: essa função é executada no meu botao cadastrar

Comment: Fiz umas modificações e coloquei um exemplo de como ficaria...

Comment: implementei aqui deu certo a verificação, tenho que implementar nas 8 atividades restantes, tenho que fazer isso em todas as 8 restantes ?

Comment: Em tese, sim. Há muito espaço para melhoria aí nesse código para evitar código duplicado. Mas isso leva tempo e estudo e vai fugir do escopo desta questão.  No comentário `"// Fazer o mesmo para as outras opções além de Yoga..."` você faz o mesmo para as outras opções.

Comment: cara deu certo, obrigado mesmo pela ajuda.